# A expressão "dar para" significando "ser possível" ou substituindo o verbo "poder" é comum em Portugal?

Tags: expressões, português-europeu, diferenças-transatlânticas, expressões-idiomáticas

No Brasil é muito comum utilizarem a expressão "dar para", como por exemplo:

> Dá pra você me ajudar? = Você pode me ajudar?
>
> Dá pra gente ir agora? = A gente pode ir agora?

E também "dar" apenas:

> Acho que não vai dar. = Acho que não vai ser possível.

Eu gostaria de saber se em EUPT também se utiliza esta expressão nestes contextos e também se existe a utilização disto com o pronome tu, como por exemplo:

> Dá pra tu me ajudares? = Tu podes me ajudar?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sim, usa-se. Mas não, não usamos com o pronome.

Vê alguns exemplos semelhantes a esses, que poderiam ser ditos em Portugal:

> - Como é, sempre dá para me ajudares com a mudança?
> - Dá para irmos agora? Ou é melhor irmos lá só amanhã?
> - Acho que não vai dar. Estou com dor de cabeça...

Mas nós omitimos o pronome. Fica implícito pela pessoa verbal.